# Visual Studio 2017 open tab in new Window

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2017, hotkeys

How does one open a current tab as a new window while using a shortcut in Visual Studio(2017)?

I know an open tab can be dragged out of the IDE and be kept as it's own window, but a shortcut for this action could be quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a keyboard shortcut to the **Window.Float** command to open a current tab as a new window.

Comment: Tools > Options > **Windows.Float** in "Show commands containing:" > shortcut in "Press shortcut Keys:". I did **Ctrl + N + W** for new window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ctrl+Tab...It wil show all the tabs you opened ..From this you can select .